# Can XML load image from Hexadecimal in Ableton Skin File (.ask)?

Tags: xml, image, hex, ableton-live

No coding background, and before I go trying to learn the needed language, is it even POSSIBLE for an XML file like Ableton Skin Files (.ask) to use an image or gradient instead of a single hex color?  Mucho thanks!
cheers,
G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the answer is no.

Since Ableton Live doesn't support rendering images or gradients in its interface, there can be no way to configure this in the XML file.